# System wont allow me to set laptop audio to default,when connected to monitor through HDMI. (PC windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, audio, hdmi

I have tried to do:

"Follow these steps after connecting the HDMI cable.

go to control panel
Hardware and Sound
Manage Audio Devices
if you have a branded audio set-up (eg. BEATS) make changes there.
Select speaker/HP
make Default and apply"

it wont let me set it to default and apply it.

Comment: Isn't it the default already? It typically is, I mean, the internal audio device.

Comment: it takes it out of default and makes the monitor the default option. When I try to switch defaults the system does not allow it. The option to apply is grayed out.

Comment: Would you please [edit] the question whenever you need to add to or correct the original information? Please also provide a screenshot showing the options/devices you have.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to fix the issue. I formatted my computer to factory settings and erased all my settings. After that it worked perfectly fine. Thank you for all of your help! ^_^

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  It looks like you accidentally created a second user account.  This will interfere with commenting on your own thread, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer since those are tied to the user account originally used to post.  See https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to get the two accounts merged.  That will allow you to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will help other users by indicating that the problem has been solved and that there is a proven solution here.